# Linq issue retrieving single value from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

Hey Guys, having an issue with Linq-to-SQL, I am basically doing the following but it is saying it is "UserProfile does not contain definition for Username" in the current context where I wrote "u.Username" but it does exist I have added UserProfile table to MyDbml.dbml and if I connect to another table it works fine.

```
TiamoDataContext context = new TiamoDataContext();

var user = (from u in context.UserProfiles
           where u.Username == UsernameLabel
          select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am flustered by what small detail I have missed out to get this to work, anyone have any clues it would be much appreciation.

Comment: Please post the content of UserProfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the compiler says it doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist.

Make sure you check case. `Username` could really be `username`. Also make sure you properly added the UserProfiles table from the database.

Without more code (or screenshots of the DBML), there's not much more we can suggest.

Comment: When you mentioned screenshots of DBML I thought I would remove and re-add UserProfile table and it works like a charm do not know what caused that thanks for your time. I think what caused it is that I am using the design view when I save in design view it mentions the .cs file for the dbml was edited outside the source editor and if I want to update it I need to click Yes to All which I may have slipped last time i did that.

Comment: Okay falsify last statement UserProfile1 needs to be its name dont know why it doesn't like UserProfile it works for me so I am happy.